# Editing Google Calendar Event not working

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

Using the latest API V3 and I'm not able (anymore - pretty sure it was working!) to edit an Google Calendar Event. 
The Calendar is a shared calendar and I tripple checked that the calendar is shared and read/write permissions are given.
Adding event to that calendar works...just editing fails.

```
private void EditGoogleEvent(string googleEventId, string calendarId, string title)
{

    Event entry = _calendarService.GetCalendarEntryByEventId(googleEventId, calendarId);

    if (entry == null)
        return;

    if (entry.Recurrence == null)
    {
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime { DateTime = From };
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime { DateTime = To };

        if (WholeDay)
        {
            start.Date = From.ToShortDateString();
            end.Date = To.ToShortDateString();
        }

        entry.Start = start;
        entry.End = end;
        entry.Summary = title;
        entry.Description = Description;
        entry.Location = Location;

        _friloCalendar.UpdateEvent(entry, googleEventId);
    }
    .....
}

public class GogoleCalendar
{
      public GogoleCalendar(string account, string connectionString)
      {

        _account = account;
        ....
       }

      public void UpdateEvent(Event entry, string googleEventId)
      {
        _calendarService.Events.Update(entry, _account, googleEventId).Execute(); 
      }
```

The exception I get:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Not Found [404]
Errors [
        Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
```

Also tried to just update the event without making any changes, results in the same exception.
That the correct EventId is used was triple checked too..as well as the calendar Id.
Cleared the auth store as well and requested a new auth key.

Out of ideas!

Comment: Hi JayTee, is this the case for all events on this calendar? Are you able to edit events on other calendars?

Comment: Hey luc, yeah, for all events, old ones, newly created ones etc. Tbh, I just tried it on 1 of 10 shared calendars I got...on my own private calendar it works though. Not at work anymore, can tell tomorrow, if its the same on other shared calendars.

Comment: Can confirm that it happens on all shared calendars.

Comment: Okay, to me it's a little suspicious you are doing an update without specifying calendar ID in the code: UpdateEvent(entry, googleEventId); Would you mind also sharing how the _friloCalendar is defined?

Comment: Updated the code...just noticed that it even doesnt work with the account of the owner of that shared calendars to edit events. For now I workarounded it, by deleting the event, setting the Id of the event to empty and adding that event again and updating my DB entry with the new event id.

Comment: So update event seems to always use account (which means the primary calendar of that account) as the calendarId. It really seems like the calendarId of the place from where you are retrieving the event is not the same as the account ID and thus the event cannot be found. You should use the same calendar ID for both.